# Azure B2C access error

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

trying to run sample code from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-web-dotnet-susi

getting error

> error : The 'Microsoft.Identity.Client 1.1.0-preview' package requires
>   NuGet client version '2.12' or above, but the current NuGet version is
>   '2.8.60318.667'.

Have simple MVC app ASP.NET app that is unsecured and want to secure it by email address from root page of web site... Simple right?

Comment: When asking questions, make sure to provide all the relevant code inside the question. Avoid posting links to it or posting images of the code. It's hard to understand what you are asking without pointing to the code, that's hosted elsewhere.

Comment: Have you tried to install the 2.12 client version?